# Is there any class similar to Silverlight's AutomationFactory for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, events, com

I found the class [AutomationFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.automation.automationfactory%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in Silverlight, that is really usefull when you want to subscribe to an event using COM objects:

```
AutomationEvent quitEvent = AutomationFactory.GetEvent(word,"Quit");
quitEvent.EventRaised += new EventHandler<AutomationEventArgs>(quitEvent_EventRaised);
```

- Do you know any similar class that could be used from **.NET**?
- Do you know the way to **bind events using automation**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was pretty sure there was one, so after a bit of searching I found the list for .Net 4.0 and it includes System.Windows.Automation; IIRC that should be the one Silverlight's AutomationFactory was based off of. [System.Windows.Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation)

Comment: it is not solution, System.Windows.Automation is used only for WPF UI

Answer (score 1):

Seems it no `AutomationFactory` analog in .Net 4.0
But you can archive it by using System.Type:

```
 var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");  
 var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type); 
 obj.InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, obj, parameter);
```

Comment: This isn't completely equivalent, because the dynamic object returned by AutomationFactory.CreateObject implements IDisposable, and disposing it releases the corresponding COM object.